# How can I process lists of different generic type?

Tags: vb.net, list, types, type-conversion

I wrote the following code:

```
Public Class FrmMain
    Private Sub FrmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        '''''''''BioSystem Section'''''''''
        Dim Bio As New BioSystem
        Dim LstBioSystem As New List(Of BioSystem)

        Bio.Heart = "Some Value"
        Bio.liver = "Some Value"
        Bio.Lungs = "Some Value"
        LstBioSystem.Add(Bio)
        '''''Add Second Value to BioSystem list
        Bio = New BioSystem
        Bio.Heart = "Some Value2"
        Bio.liver = "Some Value2"
        Bio.Lungs = "Some Value2"
        LstBioSystem.Add(Bio)

        '''''''''Car Section'''''''''
        Dim Car As New CarSystem
        Dim LstCars As New List(Of CarSystem)

        Car.Acceleration = "Some Value"
        Car.Engine = "Some Value"
        Car.Speed = "Some Value"
        Car.Weight = "Some Value"
        LstCars.Add(Car)
        '''''Add Second Value to Car list
        Car = New CarSystem
        Car.Acceleration = "Some Value2"
        Car.Engine = "Some Value"
        Car.Speed = "Some Value2"
        Car.Weight = "Some Value2"
        LstCars.Add(Car)

        ''''Output values
        WriteBio(LstBioSystem)
        WriteCar(LstCars)
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteBio(ByVal BioList As List(Of BioSystem))
        For Each Bio As BioSystem In BioList
            Console.WriteLine($"Heart:{Bio.Heart}, liver:{Bio.liver}, Lungs:{Bio.Lungs}")
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteCar(ByVal CarList As List(Of CarSystem))
            For Each Car As CarSystem In CarList
                Console.WriteLine($"Acceleration:{Car.Acceleration}, Engine:{Car.Engine}, Speed:{Car.Speed}, Weight:{Car.Weight}")
            Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class BioSystem
    Public Property Heart As String
    Public Property liver As String
    Public Property Lungs As String
End Class

Public Class CarSystem
    Public Property Engine As String
    Public Property Speed As String
    Public Property Acceleration As String
    Public Property Weight As String
End Class
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to simplify the code ?

Do something like this:

***Method** "WriteStr" Should be **replace** the "WriteBio" method and "WirteCar" method.

```
'using:

  WriteStr(LstBioSystem)
  WriteStr(LstCars)

''''
      Public Sub WriteStr(Of T)(ByVal Lst As List(Of T))
            Select Case GetType(T)
                Case GetType(BioSystem)
                    For Each Bio As BioSystem In Lst
                        Console.WriteLine($"Heart: {Bio.Heart}, liver:{Bio.liver}, Lungs:{Bio.Lungs}")
                Next
            Case GetType(CarSystem)
                For Each Car As CarSystem In Lst
                    Console.WriteLine($"Acceleration:{Car.Acceleration}, Engine:{Car.Engine}, Speed:{Car.Speed}, Weight:{Car.Weight}")
                Next
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Of course, i got errors;

> "Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to 'BioSystem'"
>
> "Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to 'CarSystem'"

Comment: you could use `List(Of Object)`

Comment: Your Car and Bio could override ToString, then it wouldnt matter what the type was

Comment: if change it to object, i got error. visual studio suggest to change "IEnumerable" in "WriteStr" method instead using list, its work but i should to know more about "IEnumerable "?
and i need to use this way. to override miss my point..

Comment: Your `BioSystem` and `CarSystem` classes have **nothing in common** with each other.  Changing to List(Of Object) and overriding ToString() for them would be the easiest solution.  If you want to force them to have something in common, then develop an **Interface** that they both must implement, then change to List(Of YourInterfaceType).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the `ToString` method your classes automatically inherit from `Object`

```
Public Class BioSystem
    Public Property Heart As String
    Public Property Liver As String
    Public Property Lungs As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"Heart: {Heart}, Liver: {Liver}, Lungs: {Lungs}"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class CarSystem
    Public Property Engine As String
    Public Property Speed As String
    Public Property Acceleration As String
    Public Property Weight As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"Acceleration: {Acceleration}, Engine: {Engine}, Speed: {Speed}, Weight: {Weight}"
    End Function
End Class
```

With these declarations you can simply write:

```
Console.WriteLine(bio)
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(car)
```

And you can write a method working for any type of list

```
Public Sub WriteList(Of T)(list As List(Of T))
    For Each item As T In list
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

You can simplify the object and list creation with object and collection initializers.

```
Dim bioSystems = new List(Of BioSystem) From {
    New BioSystem() With { .Heart =  "heart 1", .Liver =  "liver 1", .Lungs = "lung 1" },
    New BioSystem() With { .Heart =  "heart 2", .Liver =  "liver 2", .Lungs = "lung 2" }
}
WriteList(bioSystems)
```

Output:

> Heart: heart 1, Liver: liver 1, Lungs: lung 1
>   Heart: heart 2, Liver: liver 2, Lungs: lung 2

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YkE9Nz

---

**Conclusion**: `Select Case`-statements are often a strong hint that things are not done in an optimal object oriented way. Let the objects do their own things instead of doing these things in a select-case-statement outside of these objects. In the example above, each object is responsible for creating its own string representation.

**See**:
- [Inheritance and Polymorphism in VB.NET](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=28482&seqNum=6)
- [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) (C# but good explanation)